# Is there a way to run powershell scripts with a typewriter effect output?

Tags: powershell-5.0

this is more so for fun and "cool" factor, something to imitate hollywood style tech scenes.

say i have a script that does a bunch of things and outputs as write-host/verbose.

i would like to get a typewriter effect for all these outputs, as if each line is getting typed.

of course i can probably wrap every write-host/verbose into something like the [answer on this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/34dbf993-32b0-4f66-bad8-4385b0f284a5/typewriter-text-in-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell) mentions, but is there a different way to do this much easier? my script is like a 1000 lines and i dont wanna go through all outputs i have wrapping them up this way. besides, i also tee to a file so i dont wanna break any of that output either.

i do hope there is an easy wrapper around the entire script perhaps? or maybe something i can activate in the powershell console configuration/settings?

Comment: This might be of interest https://jdhitsolutions.com/blog/powershell/4445/simulating-a-powershell-demo/

Comment: I've used typed.js its awesome: https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/ not a powershell script but you can easily simulate it in browser

Comment: @jfrmilner interesting! I understand the premise for it, but I think this types out what's inside a script, not the actual output of the commands...I am not interested in the code inside to be typed out (it would be nice actually to have both) for now, but rather want the output of the commands to have effect

Comment: @Matt Berg interesting! Do you know if I can use it as a wrapper to powershell scripts?